# Macro defines for bit masks best practices

Tags: c

I lately have been using these type of defines in my code:

```
#define FLAG_1 1U
#define FLAG_2 (1U << 1)
#define FLAG_3 (1U << 2)
...
```

To kind of improve readibilty instead of writing direct hex or decimal values, and I was wondering wether I am causing my program to actually have to compute bitwise operations on each FLAG_i read or if this is something a modern C compiler (gcc 9.4.0) takes care of and just precomputes the macro value when there are no variables involved.
Any suggestion, personal opinion or insight on the matter is appreciated.

Comment: After the pre-processor has replaced the macros with their constant expressions, the compiler can (and almost certainly will) compute those constant expressions at compile time.

Comment: As with `(1+2)` the compiler will work it out, not generate code to do it at run time. In particular `#define MYSIZE (1+2)` `int array[MYSIZE]` *must* be precalculated for a static array.

Comment: The question is tagged "C", but you wrote "C/C++". Remember that in C++ the idiomatic, preferred way are static constexpr variables, due to their type safety and controlled scope.

Comment: @alagner changed it. Thanks for the tip. The library is written in C but is run on a bigger C++ application.

Comment: you just need `#define FLAG(x) (1U << (x))`

Comment: @phuclv this was just a sample for simplicity, each flag has its own descriptive name in the real program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering wether I am causing my program to actually have to compute bitwise operations on each FLAG_i

No, these are so called *integer constant expressions*. They are always evaluated at compile-time. If you check the generated machine code you'll notice that they've been replaced with a fixed constant, in this case 0x01, 0x02 or 0x04.

Writing bit masks as named constants through macros like you do is fine and common practice.